# How to transcode HLS with multiple audio tracks

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio

I am trying to create an HLS playlist with multiple audio streams. I have the following files:

1. videoHD.mp4
2. videoSD.mp4
3. audioEN.mp4
4. audioFR.mp4
5. audioIT.mp4

How would I transmux these all together in an ffmpeg command to create an HLS playlist?